# Output the number of points in a cluster from DBSCAN python

Tags: python, dbscan

Is there a way to identify the number of points that were used for each cluster from python DBSCAN?

Like my output would be 10 pairs of coordinates and I'd like to know how many original input points were used for each of those pairs.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Use something like this:

```
np.unique(labels, return_counts=True)
```

Spend more time reading the documentation.